Why is the NumPy answer different?
I'm learning NumPy. There is am equation I did in Google Colaboratory presented by my lecturer.
The answer provided by the Colaboratory is '[39 58]'. I didn’t understand how it is calculated. I asked ChatGPT, and it insists the answer is '[29, 67]'. What is the answer?
The code:
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
v = np.array([9, 10])

print(v.dot(x))
print(np.dot(v, x))

The answer provided by ChatGPT, '[29, 67]' is actually for:
print(x.dot(v))
print(np.dot(x, v))


ChatGPT can't do maths is is absolutely the wrong thing to ask.

[29, 67] is the result of x.dot(v). ChatGPT is confused.

x.dot(v) and v.dot(x) are not the same.

From the documentation, the expression x.dot(v) is the result of the matrix multiplication xv, which is [9*1+10*2, 3*9+4*10] = [29, 67], while v.dot(x) is vx, which is [9*1+10*3, 9*2+10*4] = [39, 58].
